# Automatically add copyright banner in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to configure VS Code to add a custom Copyright banner to a file? I was thinking of using a [code snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets). Is there a better way of achieving the same thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is an extension for this called [File Header Comment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=doi.fileheadercomment).

**Installation**

Open Command Palette by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, find the option `Extensions: Install Extensions` and look for **File Header Comment** extension.

**Configuration**

By default you don't have to set anything. It will detect most programming language for appropriate comment syntax. But if you want, you can set your own templates in `Preferences - User Settings`. Please consult the extension [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=doi.fileheadercomment) for more information.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If you type `ext install` and press `enter` it matches `Extensions: Disable All Installed Extensions` and does it.  Now I have to find out how to re-enable them...

Comment: @fadedbee I had the same problem. For anyone else who blindly followed this answer, go to `View`->`Extensions` then right-click each one and click `Enable`.

Answer (score 18):

There is another extension available with more options,

[psioniq File Header](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=psioniq.psi-header)

to install, press <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd> and paste the following `ext install psioniq.psi-header`

Configure your header using, `File->Preference->Settings->User Settings`

Comment: I can't seem to find this in the marketplace.

Comment: Seems to do pretty much everything EXCEPT add a boilerplate copyright banner.  Seventeen different things to turn off, and nothing I do seems to Just Insert The Copyright Boilerplate Text. :-/

Comment: lol this is the most overkilled extension i've ever seen. Why this has so many layers of configs

Answer (score 2):

Will jump into opportunity to add another one that I wrote:
[copyright-inserter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=minherz.copyright-inserter)

It works both in local and remote environments and supports *all* languages that are currently installed into your VSCode instance.

Comment: I started trying to use [File Header Comment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=doi.fileheadercomment) and while simple, this [copyright-inserter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=minherz.copyright-inserter) was even simpler.

Comment: Is there a setting to add it to all files in the project?

Comment: @MichaelPorter no, there is no such feature so far. However, the task that you mention is better suited for a CLI tools such as [addlicense](https://github.com/google/addlicense).

Answer (score 1):

I liked the Copyrighter from FordLabs.

Works like a charm!. Tried with a new Java file in vscode with copyrighter.author and copyrighter.note prefilled.

I like the way the author comes with the copyright notice and note at the bottom.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2022 {{copyrighter.author}}
 * All rights reserved.
 * {{copyrighter.note}}
 */
```

[image: Copyrighter from FordLabs]