# VS Code shortcut to add author details in new file/ old existing file at top?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

What is shortcut for adding author details at top of file in VS Code ?

or

How to create code snippet with current logged user details in VS Code,
along with shortcut for executing this snippet ?

Comment: If you're using VB.Net, try this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364172/finding-user-name-of-current-logged-in-user-using-vb-net

Comment: No, Visual Studio Code for typescript and Angular JS 4 development.

Comment: you can find your answer from here [Automatically add copyright banner in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823319/automatically-add-copyright-banner-in-vs-code)